# Mute button doesn't work on a rooted Samsung Galaxy S4

Tags: audio, samsung-galaxy-s-4

Device: GT-I9500
Android: 4.2.2, rooted

Whether I press and hold the power button and select mute from the menu or double-press the sound icon in the pull down notification menu, the phone still rings when I receive a call or a notification.

I using the volume button to turn the sound off, but now it's on vibration.

Comment: When you've tried to put it in mute mode, does the icon (a speaker with a line through it) show in the top-right of the notification bar?

Comment: Yes the icon shows up fine

Comment: Assuming your phone is in mute mode, go to `Settings > Sound > Volume`, what is the setting for Ringtone and Notification? Are they 0 (left-most)?

Comment: No, the values are the same as when they are on the Normal mode

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to solve my problem taking the following steps:

1. Install the [Clean Master (Cleaner)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cleanmaster.mguard&hl=en) app:

   > Clean Master is a Free, top-rated all-in-one cleaner app for Android™ devices.
   >   Clean - Cache files and residual files
   >   Clear - Search/call/text/etc history
   >   App Management - Move app data to the SD card and uninstall/backup apps
   >   Kills tasks - Smart memory booster
2. Clear the system cache;
3. Restart the phone.